# How to create salesforce login page inside javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

We need to integrated salesforce login in JavaScript there are working perfectly in my local host but once i have check on my live server at that time there are not working? we need to use callback url as same as my localhost url.

Is there any API to login and get access token?

Is there any library? or example you?

Comment: Can you show your code for more specifics?